# Applescript: Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed

Tags: applescript, finder

I have this script set up or rename my torrent folders, however it keeps giving me that weird finder error. It works when I don't read it from a text file, but I need that so that I don't need to select the folder all the time: Please help:

```
set read_folder to read (POSIX path of "/.torrentcleanup-prefs.txt") as text
set autofolder to (POSIX file read_folder)
set folderlist to ("")
tell application "Finder" to set folderlist to (get name of folders of folder autofolder)
repeat with i in folderlist
    set dfilepath to (POSIX path of ((autofolder & i) as text))
    set dfoldername to quoted form of POSIX path of dfilepath
    set dfolder to i
    set dmovie to quoted form of (text 1 thru ((length of dfolder) - 7) of dfolder as text)
    try
        do shell script "cd " & dfoldername & "; mv ./*.mkv ../" & dmovie & ".mkv"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "cd " & dfoldername & "; mv ./*.mp4 ../" & dmovie & ".mp4"
    end try
    do shell script "rm -r " & dfoldername & ""
end repeat
```

By the Way, the contents of "/.torrentcleanup-prefs.txt" is:

/Users/student/Desktop/FIX ME NOW/Test Folder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look at your whole script but you're reading the file wrong in the first line. You need to do it like this. So replace your first line with these two...

```
set myFile to "/.torrentcleanup-prefs.txt"
set read_folder to read (POSIX file myFile)
```